Remix IDE freezes when a contract call error occurs
When I try to call a contract function that returns an error, Remix IDE execution freezes (from https://remix.ethereum.org/). It doesn't matter what the error is, even with the banal incorrect Owner during the call. Previously, during such a call, a pop-up message with the error out of gas popped up. And the returned error was written to the ide console if, for example, revert contains its description.
Log output to the ide console:
transact to ERC721_Update.setNewCaller pending ... 

Log output to the browser console:
web3_request_manager.ts:432 Uncaught (in promise) ContractExecutionError: Error happened while trying to execute a function inside a smart contract
    at Web3RequestManager._isReverted (web3_request_manager.ts:432:48)
    at Web3RequestManager._processJsonRpcResponse (web3_request_manager.ts:373:23)
    at rejectWithError (web3_request_manager.ts:233:12)

After that, the ide freezes for 42 blocks (if I'm not confused). At the same time, any other calls are queued, but nothing happens.
Google Chrome
Version 130.0.6723.70 (Official build), (64 bit)
and
Version 130.0.6723.59 (Official build), (64 bit)
Remix IDE
v0.56.0
Metamask
Version 12.5.0
and
Version 12.4.2
and
Version 12.4.1

Can you share the code of your function? Or, ideally, the whole ERC721_Update contract?

It looks like the error has been found, I hope it will be fixed soon:
https://github.com/ethereum/remix-project/pull/5337
